# RShiny - Warning: Error in : Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (48): y

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to get my input function to link to my script but I keep getting an error. I am trying to add a check box option that filters my data on the figure.

I have tried placing the input function in my script (`input$rating`) in many different places, but I keep getting similar errors. I have looked all over the place but it seems like I cant find a common answer to fix this issue.

```
ui <- fluidPage("Retired Risks by Retired Date",
                checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "rating", label = "Risk Rating", 
                                   choices = c("Critical","Major","Moderate","Minor")),
                plotOutput("plot1"))

server <- function(input, output){
  Risk <- read.csv("C:/Users/ABakk1/Desktop/RShinyTest.csv")
  df <- data.frame(Risk$Risk_Retired_Date, Risk$Risk_Rating)
  dfsum <- df %>%
    group_by(Risk.Risk_Retired_Date, Risk.Risk_Rating) %>%
    tally()
  dfsum$Risk.Risk_Retired_Date <- factor(dfsum$Risk.Risk_Retired_Date, 
                                         levels=c("18-Jan","18-Feb","18-Mar","18-Apr",
                                                  "18-May","18-Jun","18-Jul","18-Aug",
                                                  "18-Sep","18-Oct","18-Nov","18-Dec",
                                                  "19-Jan","19-Feb"))

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    print(ggplot(dfsum, aes(x = Risk.Risk_Retired_Date, 
                            y = n<input$rating, colour = Risk.Risk_Rating ))) + 
    geom_line(aes(group = Risk.Risk_Rating), size = 1.5) + 
    scale_color_manual(name = "Risk Rating", 
                       labels = c("Critical", "Major", "Minor", "Moderate"),
          values = c("Critical"="darkred", "Major"="orangered", 
                     "Moderate"="darkorange", "Minor"="darkgoldenrod1")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,35)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          legend.key=element_blank(), legend.justification = c(0,1),
          legend.position = c(0.05,0.95), 
          legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), 
          text=element_text(size=14,  family="Arial Narrow")) +
    labs(title = "Retired Risks by Date", 
         y = "Number Risks Closed", x = "Risk Retired Date") +
    guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is what my figure should looks like:[Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeRX8.png)

I just want to add the filter option.

From what I can tell, I think I am not place the `input$rating` in the correct spot, but I have seen many different scripts placing it in different locations. Is this an issue easily solved?

Comment: Can you identify what is different between your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54833416/3358272) and this one? The data and basic code looks the same ... my guess is that this version of the question has nothing to do with `shiny`, so it might be complicating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The values stored in input$rating is a vector of characters from one or more of the following: `c("Critical","Major","Moderate","Minor")`.

In the ggplot call within the renderPlot function you are evaluating input$rating as if it were a number:

```
print(ggplot(dfsum, aes(x = Risk.Risk_Retired_Date, 
                            y = n<input$rating, colour = Risk.Risk_Rating ))) +
```

Instead, I would create a reactive object to store a new data frame prior to summation, filtered by your selection:

```
dfsum <- reactive({
df %>%
   # New code below
   filter(Risk.Risk_Rating %in% input$rating) %>%

   # Your original code
   group_by(Risk.Risk_Retired_Date, Risk.Risk_Rating) %>%
   tally()
   dfsum$Risk.Risk_Retired_Date <- factor(dfsum$Risk.Risk_Retired_Date, 
                                         levels=c("18-Jan","18-Feb","18-Mar","18-Apr",
                                                  "18-May","18-Jun","18-Jul","18-Aug",
                                                  "18-Sep","18-Oct","18-Nov","18-Dec",
                                                  "19-Jan","19-Feb"))
})
``
```